# MERN stack: Exit status 137

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, npm

I'm building my first MERN stack project and have run across a frustrating issue. After about 5-10 minutes of my script running, the site becomes unreachable. Checking my pm2 logs doesn't help me much either, as it only tells me `Exit status 137` and `errno 137`.

After doing some research it could be multiple things. Some suggest it could be CPU/RAM usage, others say it could be the node version. Does anyone know for sure what it could be as it shouldn't be using much RAM or CPU because it's currently only being accessed by myself, however if it is to do with the RAM i was already planning on upgrading after development anyways.

Let me know if you want more info, thanks in advance.

I'm on the $5.00 a month droplet on digital ocean at the moment.

- 1 GB RAM
- 1 CPU
- 25 GB SSD Disk

**2021-03-28T16_45_09_047Z-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/app/client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: CWD: /var/www/app/client
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node scripts/start.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 137  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 137
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/app/client
16 verbose Linux 5.8.0-48-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 137
22 error frontend@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
22 error Exit status 137
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 137, true ]
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue running on a different system? If it happens after running for a certain duration it could indicate a memory leak but this is completely speculative

Comment: When I was running the script from my main pc on localhost (currently on my laptop) it was working perfectly, nothing like that :/ How would I detect/fix a memory leak if thats what it is?

Comment: Look at your applications memory usage profile when you're running on your Dev box. I don't know that there is a memory leak.